# Apache mod_proxy ProxyPassMatch Regex

Tags: regex, apache, mod-proxy

I've setup Apache as a reverse proxy for a non public backend server, using mod_proxy. However one of my ProxyPassMatch directives always returns 404:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/app/files/public/orders/06_production/jobs/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/Preview%20PNG/(V[0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+.png)$ http://192.168.2.42/app/files/public/orders/06_production/jobs/$1/Preview%20PNG/$2/$3
```

This should match an incoming request like this:

```
/app/files/public/orders/06_production/jobs/P116087/Preview%20PNG/V1/bla.png
```

Any idea what's wrong with my Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
ProxyPassMatch "\A/app/files/public/orders/06_production/jobs/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/Preview PNG/(V[0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+.png)\z" "http://192.168.2.42/app/files/public/orders/06_production/jobs/$1/Preview PNG/$2/$3"
```